# Calling a function with all the original parameters

Tags: python

I'm stuck at a point in my program where I don't know whats the right way to work around it. What I have below is an attempt at explaining what I'm trying to accomplish.

What this function first does is to attempt to get some info with an accesstoken and if the token is expired it calls a another function to get a new token. At this stage, I would want it to re-run the parent function (with all the correct parameters) with the new token. This is what I have below, and I'm sure it looks shabby.

```
def do_something(accesstoken, a, b, c):
    print "I am working ..."
    r = requests.get(url + accesstoken)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        get_fresh_tokens(do_something)
        # call this function again
    else:
        print "voila!"

def get_fresh_tokens(func_to_call):
    # gets new token called accesstoken
    func_to_call(new_accesstoken) # params a, b, c are lost
```

What is the correct way of handling such a problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd pass in the parameters as extra arguments:

```
def get_fresh_tokens(func_to_call, *args, **kw):
    # gets new token called accesstoken
    func_to_call(new_accesstoken, *args, **kw)
```

and use this like:

```
get_fresh_tokens(do_something, a, b, c)
```

The positional arguments `a`, `b`, and `c` are captured in the `args` parameter for `get_fresh_tokens()`, which re-applies that list as positional arguments when calling `func_to_call()`.

The `**kw` parameter captures any keyword arguments in a dictionary, and using mirror syntax in the `func_to_call()` function will re-apply those as well if passed in.